# JQuery Gallery+Slideshow

Tags: jquery, gallery, slideshow

I am trying to build a gallery that rotate its images after every 4 seconds.
In addition to above, I need a function so that if a thumbnail image is clicked, that clicked image show up in the Big Image Area. Here is what I am doing:

```
function InOut( elem )
{
    elem.removeClass("hidden")
    .fadeIn("slow")
    .delay(2000)
    .fadeOut("slow", function(){
        if(elem.next().length > 0)
          InOut( elem.next() );
        else
          InOut( elem.siblings(':first'));
    });

}

$("a.thumbnail").click(function(){
   var MainImgID = $(this).attr("rel");
   $("#BigImage img").hide();
   InOut($("#BigImage img:nth-child("+MainImgID+")"));      
});
```

And Here is quick HTML

```
<div id="BigImage">
  <img src="images/1.jpg" id="0" class="hidden" />
  <img src="images/12.jpg" id="1" class="hidden" />
  <img src="images/10.jpg" id="2" class="hidden" />
</div>

<div id="thumb">
  <ul>
    <li><a rel="0"><img src="images/thumbs/1.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a rel="1"><img src="images/thumbs/12.jpg" /></a></li>
   <li><a rel="2"><img src="images/thumbs/10.jpg" /></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**PROBLEM**
The problem is that auto-rotation messed up when I click the thumbnail image. It starts another slideshow right below the main image. If I click again, it start another (third) slideshow below and so on....

Please help...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not run `InOut` in the callback, just make the other images hide, and the big image show like this: (assuming they have id that is in order)

```
$("a.thumbnail").click(function(){
   var MainImgID = $(this).attr("rel");
   $("#BigImage img").hide().eq(MainImgID).show();      
});
```

Comment: Thats right but in this case auto-rotation of BigImages wont work